# Decrease an object with values

Tags: scale

Good Morning

I need to decrease an object on edit mode so it gets to 60cm height, but when I use the scale tool, it is proportionally decreased. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Please provide a .blendfile https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look.
Scale tool in 2.8 has three handles, each for one axis. But the scaling is relative, so achieving an exact distance might be tricky.

Comment: @JachymMichal (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6847/)

Comment: Hey there. This question doesn't allow answers, because it was marked as a duplicate. However I checked your file, and all I said before works. You can also switch blender to milimeters in *Properties panel->Scene->Units.* for control of the size.

Comment: @JachymMichal But how I can scale my object to 2cm height for example? Sorry but I still don't understand

Comment: You can just type it into the dimensions panel. Just type over the current value :).

Comment: @JachymMichal But into the dimension panel just exist a relative value. I need to change it for real value for example 2cm

Comment: not the scale panel. The dimensions panel has absolute values. https://imgur.com/a/8u1TeYN

Comment: @JachymMichal I find it. But the dimensions can't be changed on edit mode